# Remove line breaks or return codes from string

Tags: string-manipulation

I have imported string data, which appears to have line breaks or return codes in it invisible in a notebook input cell.

Copying a string and pasting into Apple Pages with control codes showing gets me this:

[image]

I've looked at `StringDelete`, but can't see a way to make it work for control characters.

How can I remove them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove line breaks from a string with `StringDelete`, you can simply do this:

```
string = 
  "I have imported string data, which appears to have line breaks or return codes in it invisible in a notebook input cell.

  Copying a string and pasting into Apple Pages with control codes showing gets me this:";

StringDelete[string, "\n" | "\r"]

(*
==> "I have imported string data, which appears to have line breaks or return codes in it invisible in a notebook input cell.Copying a string and pasting into Apple Pages with control codes showing gets me this:"
*)
```

Comment: I knew if had to have a simple solution.  Thx.